# How to calculate the total resistance of a parallel circuit in series

Tags: circuit-analysis, parallel

I have a simple question on resistance calculation but I can't work it out. The diagram is from the site [All About Circuits](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-7/what-is-a-series-parallel-circuit/):

[image]

I can't figure out why the top parallel total resistance for example is 71 ohms. I thought the calculation for this would be:

$$1/Rt=1/100+1/250$$
$$1/Rt=0.1+0.04=0.104$$
$$Rt=1/0.104=9.6$$

Have I missed something obvious? Appreciating that the answer is probably simple but if I don't ask I'll never find out...

Comment: 1/100=0.01 and 1/25=0.004     0.01+0.004=0.014    1/0.014=71.42

Comment: For R1 and R2 parallel resistance = \$\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{1}{R1}+\dfrac{1}{R2}}\$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you do it is correct, but the numbers don't check out:

\$\frac{1}{100 \Omega}\$ is 0.01 S and not 0.1. \$\frac{1}{250 \Omega}\$ is 0.004 S and not 0.04. So you end up with 0.0104 S, of which the inverse is 71.429 \$\Omega\$ (which has way to many digits).

Comment: Aha. So it is because I'm stupid after all....Thanks for your patience

Comment: You're not stupid, you just weren't careful or concentrated enough @user91280.